# Will the Sony Walkman NWZ-S545 work with Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware, compatibility, sony

So I might be getting a new MP3 player and I think that is going to be the Sony Walkman NWZ-S545. I don't want to have the same situation with the last MP3 player, which was the Shuffle and it didn't have good compatibility with Ubuntu so I was wondering if the Sony Walkman NWZ-S545 would work with Ubuntu?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise going with a different mp3 player. A lot of people on the web seem to have issues with making the walkman interact smoothly with audio programs.

If you want that particular mp3 player, here's how to make it work with ubuntu:

http://ubuntu-virginia.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=866297

Otherwise, I'd recommend a generic used iPod nano/classic/touch. They are *almost* always perfectly compatible.

Good Luck!

EDIT: Additional How-To: kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3096598

Comment: I want a good sound quality MP3 player

Comment: AFAIK, the mp3 player has no impact on the sound quality. The headphones, as well as the mp3 file ITSELF, are the culprits for bad/shoddy quality.

Comment: Compare the iPod and the Walkman. :D Lol, thanks for the link, that was a quick response. :)

Comment: Ah, turns out you were right on that bit. Here's a quote I found: MP3/M4A/AAC Sound quality depends upon three things:

a) The source quality (crap in = crap out)
b) Encoding bit rate - the higher the better but that increases file size. Good music will come at 192 kbps or higher.
c) The quality of headphones or sound system.

Comment: Okay, just to make sure, it works with Ubuntu, right?

Comment: It will, in the end. You may have to do some tweaking (issues might have been resolved with newer Ubuntu releases. The links I posted are 1+ year old.)

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks. :D This new site is awesome. Really quick.

Comment: ^.^ I'd appreciate it if you'd 'accept' the answer so people don't continue to post on a resolved question. (unless you are still waiting for more posts).

Comment: Ohhh, sorry. I was looking for the "Mark thread as Solved" button. :P