# Sony Media Go - Ubuntu OS Compatible?

Tags: compatibility, sony

Can Sony Media Go (management system for Sony walkman mp3 music) be saved on an Ubuntu operating system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will the Sony Walkman NWZ-S545 work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5786/will-the-sony-walkman-nwz-s545-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: See http://alternativeto.net/software/sony-media-go/?platform=linux

Comment: Oh and please: always list the features for something like that. The above link claims Clementine and Rhythmbox can be used as a replacement for SMG but ... most of us know nothing about that software or rather avoid windows software.

Answer (score 0):

It's a windows program so you it probably won't work normaly. You can either try using WINE (Package to use windows programs on linux) or find an alternative that can do the same. Regards, ADDB

Comment: I would always suggest a sandboxed Windows virtuzalized (vmware/virtual box) and never trust on wine